# Can I test an app on all devices without purchasing all devices?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, web-application, mobile-automation

Is there any way to test an app on all devices without purchasing all devices?

Comment: Use Browserstack- https://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: The facetious answer is "yes". And "no". There are multiple services that provide testing on a wide variety of devices, but they probably don't cover all possible devices because obsolete devices won't be included.

Comment: Voting to close because googling the title would OP give bunch of service providers, and selecting between them is a matter of opinion and constraints not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

In order to do that, you can purchase a cloud based service like SauceLabs, BrowserStack or even try Amazon's [Device Farm](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/), which would give you the capability of testing your apps, across different platforms, on different devices.

There are other services too that offer this capability , and so you can search for this in and whatever suites your budget and needs , you should go for it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes  there are multiple website which provide App testing functionality

- pCloudy: https://www.pcloudy.com/
- experitest: https://experitest.com/
- Amazon's Device Farm
- testobject: https://testobject.com/

Answer (score 0):

Google's firebase test lab is another option that I don't see listed in the other answers so far. https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab ;

pcloudy, that was listed in one of the other answers, also supports testing automation through integration with appium.

Answer (score 0):

[BitBar](https://bitbar.com/) = lots of devices, lots of supported test frameworks

Answer (score 0):

This is a common requirement in [mobile testing services](https://wwwqasource.com/mobile-qa) and for the same we can test an app on different online platforms without purchasing the real devices and below are some of them:
1. [Browser Stack](https://www.browserstack.com/)
2. Sauce Labs
3. Device Farm
But these platforms are paid one and require a subscription to get the benefits.

IMP: App build should also be made compatible to run these in Online Platforms.